# xcode - pickerview not displaying in non-arc mode

Tags: ios, arrays, xcode

I am trying to use a PickerView with ARC turned off, it has become a nightnmare, will be extremely grateful if someone could please have a quick look kindly suggest how to solve...thnx in advance
the issue is that the rest of my app is non-arc and so i want to add the pickerview as a class that can operate as a viewcontroller in the project...
I had multiple pickers working beautifully 4 days ago with arc but when i turned arc off it became a nightmare...to identify the precise issue i have removed all the frills and am just working with a bare structure now....there are no errors but the data from the array is not displaying...i am listing the header and omplementation files below...the reason i had linked the folder was to make the interface file available....so that the connections can be checked too...but we can look at that after the basic code is first checked....thanks so much for your kind attention and time...

### .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface HomeViewController : UIViewController        UIPickerViewDataSource,UIPickerViewDelegate>
{NSArray *categoryTypes;
}
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *categoryTypePicker;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *categoryTypeBtn;
```

### @end

### .m

```
#import "HomeViewController.h"

@interface HomeViewController ()

#define kPICKER1COLUMN 1
#define kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG 21
#define kCATEGORYTYPEBTN 31

@end


@implementation HomeViewController

@synthesize categoryTypeBtn;
@synthesize categoryTypePicker;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
if (self) {

        categoryTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Appetizers",@"Breakfast",@"Dessert",@"Drinks",
                     @"Main Dish/Entree", @"Salad", @"Side Dish", @"Soup", @"Snack", 
                     @"Baby Food", @"Pet Food", nil];
    }
    return self;
}



- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    categoryTypePicker.tag = kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG;

    categoryTypePicker.showsSelectionIndicator = TRUE;
    categoryTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    categoryTypePicker.delegate = self;
    self.categoryTypePicker.dataSource = self;
    self.categoryTypePicker.delegate = self;
    [self.categoryTypePicker reloadAllComponents];
    categoryTypePicker.hidden = YES;
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (int)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
        return kPICKER1COLUMN;
    else { return 0; }
}

- (int)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
        return [categoryTypes count];
    else { return 0; }
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
        return [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:row];
    else { return 0; }
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    if (pickerView.tag == kCATEGORYTYPEPICKERTAG)
    {
        NSString *categoryType  = [categoryTypes objectAtIndex:[categoryTypePicker selectedRowInComponent:0]];
        [categoryTypeBtn setTitle:categoryType forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        NSLog(@"%@", categoryType);

    }

    pickerView.hidden=YES;
}


-(IBAction) showCategoryTypePicker{

        {
        [self.view addSubview:categoryTypePicker];
        categoryTypePicker.hidden = NO;

    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];

}


- (void)dealloc {
    [categoryTypes release];
    [categoryTypePicker release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

---

i will await your reply...

[linktocode](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1W8dDSQl78AbHVacDRqbmJIU28&usp=sharing)

Comment: It is bad attitude to show link to you're whole project.Try to show problem in more descriptive way.And define code parts that are for you not clear!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: sorry for that, actually i have exhausted all answers on the stackoverflow site that is why i wanted to keep it brief, it is not lack of attitude just tiredness after many many hours of trying, and the feeling that it must be a minute thing that i am missing...

Comment: Is initWithNibName:bundle: being called? It looks like you're hiding and unhiding your picker, which I presume you added to your controller in a xib or storyboard, so you shouldn't be adding it as a subview in your button method. Also, make sure your button is hooked up to its action, since you shouldn't see the picker until you touch that button.

Answer (score 1):

[dont have access to comments so am responding here] thanks rdelmar i commented out the init-bundle and the subview of the button but now the build is giving the error bad access...i have a rough idea of what is going on but don't know how to address it...the issue is basically that the array is not retained for the objectAtIndex call...need some way of retaining it...thnx